# How can I install Mesa drivers from source?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling, gpu-driver, mesa

I followed [this](https://mesa3d.org/meson.html) guide but my driver version isn't changed. I compiled the  Mesa 19.0.0 drivers without any issues but glxinfo -B output says I still have old drivers.

Btw, I have the latest Meson and Ninja versions.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the old drivers? Linux Package manager does not do this. If you haven't already you should check out https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/amdgpu-installation. Need to elaborate your build more, system info, and what version of Linux your using.

Comment: Well, I no longer need to compile the drivers from source. Thanks anyways.